# jwplayer custom header with token for authorization

Tags: javascript, web-services, jwplayer, jwplayer7

We want to use jwplayer for playing some mp4 files. These files have got from web-service cross domain with methods Get or Set.
How we can set authorization header for jwplayer in its own request to get the video file ? The header is for sending current token.

thanks for any reply

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The JW Player content service includes a security feature that allows you to restrict public access to videos or to videos plus players. This feature is enabled in the dashboard. When enabled, content can only be requested by constructing so-called signed links. These links will expire after a short time, preventing unauthorized sharing or leeching of your content. [You can find documentation on URL token signing here](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/reference/v1/content_signing.html?highlight=authorization%20header).

Comment: Thanks @JosieKeller ,I've seen that before ,but if you take a look at this URL : Jwplayer Release notes you'll see they added this feature in beta version, Is there any reference how to use it in version 7.7 Beta ?